# How to set the Data Source in a VEGA barchart?

Tags: javascript, vega

I am following a [basic VEGA tutorial where a Barchart is rendered](https://vega.github.io/vega/tutorials/bar-chart/).
This works as long as all the data is in the JSON settings file that is first loaded. But the tutorial states that the data source can also be set as follows:

- loaded from the web by using the url property (including JSON and CSV files),
- derived from a previously defined data set using the source property, or
- **left undefined and dynamically set when the visualization is constructed**.

I am going for the last option, where I set the data in my javascript file. But none of my tries work. No data is rendered. How do I set the data source in a VEGA chart dynamically?

My code

```
let testData = [
    {"category": "A","amount": 66},
    {"category": "B","amount": 33}
]


fetch('tablespecs.json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(spec => render(spec))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))


function render(spec) {
    let view = new vega.View(vega.parse(spec), {
        renderer: 'canvas',                 
        container: '#view',                
        hover: true,
        source:testData                       // not working
    })

    view.source = testData                    // not working
    view.data.source = testData               // not working
    view.data = testData                      // not working

    view.runAsync()
}
```

The table specs are copied directly from the tutorial page. I just left out the `values` property. I also tried leaving out the entire `data` property.

Specs JSON

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
    "width": 400,
    "height": 200,
    "padding": 5,
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "table",
            // removed values here
        }
    ],
    // ... rest of barchart specs unchanged from example
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue.. as I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem may be related to not awaiting results before injecting them into the view. The below code works for updating the data after the view has been rendered. Make sure that the function containing this code is marked as async.

```
 await this.view.change('table', vega.changeset().remove(vega.truthy).insert(
      [
        {'category': 'A', 'amount': 21},
        {'category': 'B', 'amount': 551},
        {'category': 'C', 'amount': 471},
        {'category': 'D', 'amount': 91},
        {'category': 'E', 'amount': 85},
        {'category': 'F', 'amount': 211},
        {'category': 'G', 'amount': 91},
        {'category': 'H', 'amount': 74}
      ]
    )).runAsync();
```

Source: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#data-and-scales